# Custom UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a circular UIImageview. To do that, I am using UIBezierPath's `stroke` with colour being the image. In the storyboard, I specified the class for the imageView to be my custom UIImageView. It didn't work.

Here is my Custom UIImageView

```
@implementation CustomImageView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
} 


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIBezierPath *circularpath = [[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
    CGRect Rect = CGRectMake(96, 54, 128, 128);//338
    //CGPoint mypoint = CGPointMake(Rect.origin.x + (Rect.size.width / 2), Rect.origin.y + (Rect.size.height / 2));
    circularpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:Rect];
    circularpath.lineWidth = 5.0;
    [[UIColor blueColor]setStroke];
    UIImage *ori = [UIImage imageNamed:@"drogba.jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ori.CGImage scale:1.45 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    [[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image]setFill];
    NSLog(@"Circular path:%@", circularpath);
    [circularpath stroke];

}
```

Here is how I have declared it in the Controller

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomImageView *dpImage;
```

Comment: Why are you using UIImageView? why not just UIView? Maybe thats the problem

Comment: I was using UIImageView for the image property that it has

Comment: So don't. Save the image you render in some local instance, and create your own image property.

Comment: @AviTsadok, do you have any reason to believe that your suggestion will help? I don't see it.

Comment: @vikingosegundo UIImageView handle rendering different than what is written here.If you need to render your own core graphics code, UIImageView it's not the right class. You need to use regular UIView. Now, I don't know if thats the problem, but we need to clean this out.

Comment: @AviTsadok and nupac, personally I'd say a custom image view is not needed. But if you want to have one, subclass is from UIView and have a subview that is a plain image view. add it with all desired eye candy in `layoutSubview`, don't use `drawRect:`for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't implement `drawRect:` in a `UIImageView` subclass.

To create a circular image view, use a standard image view and set the border (`borderColor`, `borderWidth`) and corner radius on the image views layer (`cornerRadius`).

---

For a circular view the corner radius needs to be set to half of the width (and the view should obviously be square).

```
// image should be squared. otherwise you have to recalculate frame and 
// set an appropriate scale fill mode.
UIImageView *imageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width /2;
```

Comment: I tried corner radius with various values and I never get a perfect circle

Comment: @nupac see my answer below. cornerradius should be half of imageview width. then only you can get perfect circle.

Comment: @Wain: I hope you don't mind I added some code to illustrate your solution.

Comment: so the trick is to use half the width of the uiimageview. Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Error in your code is: You have done `storking in circular Path`. But You `didn't assign` that path to any `layer`. So It won't appear in view.

Second, No need to implement UIImageview subclass. You can create circular image view by doing some workaround with layer of UIImageview's property. `(cornerradius, borderwidth,bordercolor)`.
Here corner radius must be **half of UIImageview width**. After setting these layer settings, you can init your image.